# How to compare and interpret results of two neural networks models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I made two models of neural networks(different architectures), the first one gave me as result:

- Training Loss: 0.4195
- Training Acc: 0.8325
- Training Recall: 0.7266
- Validation Loss: 0.4331
- Validation Acc: 0.8483
- Validation Recall: 0.7400
- Test Acc: 0.7864
- Test Recall: 0.7657

The second one:

- Training Loss: 0.3354
- Training Acc: 0.8583
- Training Recall: 0.7791
- Validation Loss: 0.3791
- Validation Acc: 0.8493
- Validation Recall: 0.7773
- Test Acc: 0.8254
- Test Recall: 0.7602

The problem there is that although the second model gives a better loss value, the first model gives a better result on the test set, so how can we interpret and compare these results? and does it have a way to test the stability of a model?

NB: the hyper parameters are the same for two models (batch size, learning rate, optimization algorithm) and the same validation and training sets

Comment: Which metric, or a metric not calculated, is closest to your business problem or whatever you are trying to solve for? Start with the metric that is closest to your issue and then work backwards to other metrics to gain insight and maybe tie breakers. And the metrics above need a cutoff value. Is that the optimal cutoff value for each model and the business problem?

Comment: Yes, these results are of the best models during training,   I depend on recall metric to get the best one.

Comment: I am assuming that test is the hold-out and was not examined. That is the data to get an idea of performance just before deployment. Validation is the data the models were compared against. Never look at the hold out set until the model is ready to go. If recall is the metric you need and these are both with the optimal cutoff value, then model 2 looks slightly better from these metrics. You can derive back to how many items are wrongly classified. There are lots of other ways to determine a preferred model.

Comment: You don't use test performance to choose a model. Such decisions are made on the validation data.

Comment: Craig and Michael, thank you for your answers, indeed I am doing a research work, I have two different architectures and I would like to make a performance comparison, I have 3 sets, training, validation and test. After the training phase of two neural network models, and with the selection of the best model according to the "recall" method, and to compare the performance of two models, I applied these models on the test set, so I need a scientific method to make the comparison.

Comment: If using F1 Score, the second is clearly better.